# Apache POI, align text to left and other text to right in same row

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, apache-poi-4

I'm using Apache POI to create excel export file (.xlsx with XSSF).
I'm having one issue with borders between cells.

I need to have few cells merged into one row and in that row I need to have one text aligned to the left, and another text aligned to the right, something like:

[image]

but without that border in between.

To get what you see in the image I used two merged areas, in one I aligned text to the left and in the other one I aligned text to the right, I'm not sure if there is a better/more convenient way to do this or not, if you know it please write it in the answer, but for my approach right now the issue is with that border, can I remove it? I tried setting right border for first merged area to `NONE` and setting left border for the second merged area to `NONE` as well, but it doesn't work.

How should I handle this?

Comment: how about you set the right border color to white for the left cell and set the left border to white for the right cell, that will get rid of the grey line :  leftCell.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
rightCell.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

Comment: @AbdelhalimJean Thank you for the suggestion, but I also tried that already :D, it didn't work two days ago, but I'll give it another go tonight and will post back if it works.

Comment: @AbdelhalimJean Tried it again, didn't work.

Comment: can you please share some code so I can run it an do the necessary changes

Comment: Could you do it using the values found in https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html to set the colour using the method found at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#setCellStyleProperty-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object- ?  I know you said you've done that already but this looks like a different route?  I'd probably also try to find something that made sure the background was the same colour as this border.  Sorry - no time to make a try at it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.RegionUtil;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try(Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")){
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

            Font font = wb.createFont();
            font.setBold(true);
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)11);

            CellRangeAddress leftCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(
                0,
                1,
                CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"),
                CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("E")
            );
            sheet.addMergedRegion(leftCellRangeAddress);
            CellRangeAddress rightCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(
                0,
                1,
                CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("F"),
                CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("H")
            );
            sheet.addMergedRegion(rightCellRangeAddress);
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

            Cell leftCell = row.createCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"));
            leftCell.setCellValue("LEFT");
            leftCell.getCellStyle().setFont(font);
            CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(leftCell, VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            CellUtil.setAlignment(leftCell, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
            RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN, leftCellRangeAddress, sheet);
            RegionUtil.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex(), leftCellRangeAddress, sheet);

            Cell rightCell = row.createCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("F"));
            rightCell.setCellValue("RIGHT");
            rightCell.getCellStyle().setFont(font);
            CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(rightCell, VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            CellUtil.setAlignment(rightCell, HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
            RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN, rightCellRangeAddress, sheet);
            RegionUtil.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex(), rightCellRangeAddress, sheet);

            wb.write(fos);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want the grey border on the bottom you can add

```
CellRangeAddress firstRowRegion = new CellRangeAddress(
    0,
    1,
    CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"),
    CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("H")
);
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THICK, firstRowRegion, sheet);
RegionUtil.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex(), firstRowRegion, sheet);
```

and you'll get

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. When you initially commented to try and change colors I said I already tried it, but I tried it using style object, I would set right and left border colors on the style and then apply that style to specified cells and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What your screenshot shows is a gridline and not a border line. That's a difference in spreadsheets. The gridlines are shown in application window only to see the cells better. They will not be printed.

If you dont want to see the gridlines you either could switching to not showing gridlines for the whole sheet, what i do not recommend, or you could set white border lines which will overpaint some of the gridlines then.

Since you have tagged `apache-poi-4` I will show a complete example which uses the advanced methods of `CellUtil` and `PropertyTemplate` to produce what you seems to want.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelLeftRight {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   //create font with bigger size
   Font font = workbook.createFont();
   font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)24);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   //merge A1:E2
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
    0, //first row (0-based)
    1, //last row  (0-based)
    0, //first column (0-based)
    4  //last column  (0-based)
   ));

   //merge F1:H2
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
    0, //first row (0-based)
    1, //last row  (0-based)
    5, //first column (0-based)
    7  //last column  (0-based)
   ));

   //create row 1
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   //create cell A1
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("LEFT");
   CellUtil.setFont(cell, font);
   CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(cell, VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
   //create cell F1
   cell = row.createCell(5);
   cell.setCellValue("RIGHT");
   CellUtil.setFont(cell, font);
   CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(cell, VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
   CellUtil.setAlignment(cell, HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
 
   PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate = new PropertyTemplate();
   //paint all inside borders white on A1:H2
   propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 0, 7), 
    BorderStyle.THIN, IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex(), BorderExtent.INSIDE);
   //paint all bottom borders thick gray on A2:H2
   propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 7), 
    BorderStyle.THICK, IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex(), BorderExtent.BOTTOM);
   propertyTemplate.applyBorders(sheet);

   sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress(3, 0));

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but in this case, your answer didn't work out, however answer provided by @AbdelhalimJean below did, I'm not sure what's the difference between two approaches yet, I'm pretty new to POI library, but thanks again.